# Einstein metrics on compact nilmanifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is there an Einstein metric on a compact nilmanifold (compact quotient of a non-abelian nilpotent Lie group) in dimension > 3 ?

Comment: At least, non-abelian nilpotent Lie groups do not admit left-invariant Einstein metrics (Milnor).

Comment: Thanks AP :-)  These compact non-abelian nilmanifolds do not admit any metric with non-negative Ricci curvature, so the Einstein metric, if it exists, must have negative Einstein constant. Even for the torus it's still not known (as far as I am aware of) whether there is an Einstein metric with negative constant.